# Is it necessary to return pointer type in sync.Pool New function?

Tags: go

I saw the [issue](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/16323) on Github which says sync.Pool should be used **only** with pointer types, for example:

```
var TPool = sync.Pool{
    New: func() interface{} {
       return new(T)
    },
}
```

Does it make sense? What about `return T{}` and which is the better choice, why?

Comment: It depends on what T is and how the value is used.    Show the definition of T.

Comment: This is not a duplicate, this question is about how to properly use a sync.Pool. The other question is about allocation, a technical issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The whole point of `sync.Pool` is to avoid (expensive) allocations. Large-ish buffers, etc. You allocate a few buffers and they stay in memory, available for reuse. Hence the use of pointers.

But here you'll be copying the values on every step, defeating the purpose. (Assuming your `T` is a "normal" struct and not something like `SliceHeader`)

Comment: Why it would be copied on every step? I don't think it would do allocations when I  **Get** the existing instance (`T{}`) from the pool (Assuming GC not executed yet).

Comment: @cncal that's how value types work. They're copied. You won't get the object from the pool, you'll get its copy. For this very reason, if your method mutates your struct, it must have pointer receiver.

Comment: @cncal: actually, everything in go is pass-by-value (pass-by-copy), I think. Only when your value is a pointer, you don't care that it's a copy (of another pointer).

Comment: I get it... :).

Comment: What if T is a slice ? It's a small structure. It's not a problem to be copied. What is important is the buffer it references with a pointer. Nevertheless, if I pass a slice value, won't it be "boxed" due to the `interface{}` type ?

Comment: Does it still provide benefits to use sync.Pool when dealing with a large number of small objects?

Answer (score 2):

It is not necessary. In most cases it should be a pointer as you want to share an object, not to make copies.

In some use cases this can be a non pointer type, like an id of some external resource. I can imagine a pool of paths (mounted disk drives) represented with strings where some large file operations are being conducted.

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/16323) is the similar issue on github, does it make sense?